# Weird bug with a function that gives the connected component of a triangular mesh

Tags: c++, mesh

i am trying to code a function in `C++` that gives me the connected components of a triangular mesh.
I have a custom class that modelize a 3D triangular mesh.
My goal is to obtain a `std::vector<Mesh2d>`  with contain a connected component of my mesh in each component.

```cpp
class Mesh2d{
    
    std::vector<R3>* node_ptr;
    std::vector<Elt2d> elt;
public:
    
    Mesh2d(){};
    Mesh2d(std::vector<R3>& node){}
    void Load(const string& filename){}
    void PushBack(const Elt2d& e){}
    std::vector<Elt2d>::iterator begin(){}
    std::vector<Elt2d>::iterator end(){}
    std::vector<int> Num(const int& j) const {}
    void Plot(string filename) const {}
    const Elt2d& operator[](const int& j) const {}
    std::vector<Elt2d> const GetElt() const {}
    void GetBoundary(Mesh& mesh){} 
    friend  std::vector<Elt2d> adj(Elt2d e, Mesh2d mesh){}
    friend int find_index(Elt2d e,Mesh2d mesh){}
    

    friend void DFS(int j , std::vector<bool> visited, Mesh2d boundary, std::vector<Mesh2d> ConnectedComponents, int n){
         visited[j] = true;

        std::cout<<"visited = " << visited << std::endl;
        ConnectedComponents[n].PushBack(boundary[j]);
        Elt2d e = boundary[j];
        std::vector<Elt2d> neighbor = adj(e,boundary);
        for(int i = 0; i<neighbor.size(); ++i){
         //   std::cout<<"i = " << i << std::endl;
            int p = find_index(neighbor[i], boundary);
            if(visited[p] == false){
                DFS(p, visited, boundary, ConnectedComponents, n);
            }
            
             
            
        }
    }


    std::vector<Mesh2d> Boundary(Mesh mesh){
        Mesh2d boundary;
        boundary.GetBoundary(mesh);
        std::vector<Mesh2d> ConnectedComponents;
        std::vector<bool> visited(boundary.NbElt(),false);
        std::vector<bool> True(boundary.NbElt(),true);
        int k = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<boundary.NbElt(); ++j){
            ConnectedComponents.resize(k+1);
            std::cout<<"j =" << j << std::endl;
            Elt2d e = boundary[j];
            if(visited[j]==false){

                DFS(j, visited, boundary, ConnectedComponents,k);
                ConnectedComponents[k].PushBack(boundary[j]);
                std::cout<< "NbCC = " << ConnectedComponents.size() << std::endl;
                
            
            



            }

            ++k;
           std::cout<<"k = " << k << std::endl;
            
        }
        return ConnectedComponents;
    }
};
```

Where `R3` and `Elt2d` are custom class representing 3D vectors and triangle.
My problem is with the two function `DFS` and `Boundary`, i'm using a depth-first search algorithm to explore my mesh (with the triangle as nodes). But i am getting a strange bug where my vector `visited` changes some of its value to `false`. If I print my `visited` vector for a small mesh i get this :

```
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
visited = 1 1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I have absolutely no clue why it's happening.
Please keep in mind that I am a beginner with `C++` and some part (or a lot) of my code can look silly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: *I have absolutely no clue why it's happening* -- 1) Use the debugger.  2) Change the access to all of your vectors by replacing `[ ]` with the `at()` function.  This will check if you are going out-of-bounds within your code.  3) Post a [mcve], so that we can actually run something.

Comment: `Mesh2d(){};` -- This failed to initialize the pointer member.  Also `Mesh2d` violates the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three), yet you're passing it by value to the `DFS` function.  You really need to post a [mcve], because you have multiple issues with the code you have now.

Comment: Should i post my `Elt2d` class and the whole `Mesh2d` and `Mesh` class then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `visited` by value:

```cpp
void DFS(int j, std::vector<bool> visited, Mesh2d boundary, std::vector<Mesh2d> ConnectedComponents, int n)
```

That means that this vector is copied each time you call the `DFS` function, and no values of the original vector are changed. You observe that as the values "restored" whenever you return from the function.

Pass the vector by reference instead:

```cpp
void DFS(int j, std::vector<bool> &visited, Mesh2d &boundary, std::vector<Mesh2d> &ConnectedComponents, int n)
```

Revise the rest of the code, you never pass the "heavy" objects by referece. That is at least inefficient.